# PHP session variable with the userID (integer) is carrying wrong value to another webpage

Tags: php, variables, session, integer

I'm a newbie at php, trying to create a home-made php website connected to a MySQL database for my own stuff. The logged-in users are supposed to be able to edit and delete only the data that they themselves insert into several of the DB tables. The webpages for users´ registration, login, landing after login (in this case users_dashboard.php) are working well.

THE PROBLEM: is with creating a session variable to store the userID when the user logs in, so that it can be used to filter the user´s items from other tables (e.g. products) and display them in other webpages. I do not get any error message but regardless of which user I login, the echo statement in the users_dashboard.php webpage always returns "1", and not the actual user id value. I have always made sure to logout before testing it with a different user.

This is the extra code I inserted in the login page to create the session variable:

```
<?php $_SESSION['uid'] = $row_rsUserLogin['userID']; ?>
```

And this is the code I added to the page that loads after successful login (users_dashboard.php), just to test if the session variable was actually storing the proper value:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me identify the cause for this problem.

ADDITIONAL CONTEXT INFO:
The recordset used in it is called rsUserLogin.
The userID is the primary key in the users table (the usual: INT, AUTO_Increment, primary key), and the corresponding value is used as foreign key in the other tables, to relate them back to each specific user.

I´m using Dreamweaver CS6 and WampServer 2.5 (PHP 5.5.12, MySQL 5.6.17). The Dreamweaver Bindings panel has the possibility to add a session variable but it does not seem to be doing anything (I was not able to identify any new code added with it).

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:
i) added the field userID to one of the queries that was already in the page's code (it did not work if I added it at the end of the php code, right before the html section) and,
ii) after the session variables that were already being assigned, added this code:

$_SESSION['uid'] = mysql_result($LoginRS, 0);

where $LoginRS is the resource variable that holds the result of the relevant mysql_query. "0" is because there is only record that fulfills the query conditions, eheh!

Uhuh!! : ))